# Is logistic regression used for unconstrained or constrained optimisation problems?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, logistic-regression

Is logistic regression used for unconstrained or constrained optimization problems, and why?

Comment: Hi Miko. You were asking two separate questions here, so I removed your second question about SVMs. Here you can ask about logistic regression and, in another post, you can ask about SVM.